# The $L^\infty$ norm of Hardy-Littlewood function equal the $L^\infty$ norm of the original function

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

Since
$$Mf(x) = \sup_{x\in I} \frac{1}{|I|} \int_I |f(y)| dy \leq \|f\|_{\infty},$$
we have
$$ \|Mf\|_{\infty} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}.$$
On the other hand, it holds
$$|f(x)| \leq Mf(x) \quad a.e.,$$ which means
$$\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \|Mf\|_{\infty}.$$
Therefore,
$\|f\|_{\infty} = \|Mf\|_{\infty}.$
Am I right?

Comment: The first display makes no sense: $x$ appears as an argument in the LHS and yet is quantified over (in the $\sup$) in the RHS.

Comment: It does make sense: For fixed $x$ you take the supremum over all $I$ containing $x$.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich following Jochen's comment, you could read it as the supremum over all $I\ni x$

Comment: Hello. I think you could provide some context. Also say what $f$ is, what $I$ is, etc...

Comment: I would also change the confusing notation (involving $x\in I$).

Comment: I don't think so. $Mf(x)$ is the supremum of all (centered, in your example) averages that can be done around point $x$. I don't see why you should have $|f|\leq Mf$ almost everywhere. For instance if you pick a highly oscillating function $f(x):=\sin(1/x)$ I expect that $Mf < |f|$ happens a lot.

Comment: I haven't thought deeply about the question but I would like to push back a little against the suggestions/complaints regarding notation, since this kind of shorthand is very common when working with this kind of harmonic analysis - look up BMO, for instance

Comment: It is true; the inequality $|f(x) \leq Mf(x) $ a.e. follows from the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.